# Python continue and break difference

Tags: python, oop, continue

I am get ting deeper into understanding the purpose of continue. I know that `continue` goes back to the top of the loop, `break` stops execution, and `pass` does nothing. If `continue` goes back to the top of the loop would it not be recursive? In my example, the continue is used to stop execution.

```
import re
value = []
items=[x for x in raw_input().split(',')]
for p in items:
    if len(p)<6 or len(p)>12:
        continue
    else:
        pass
    if not re.search("[a-z]",p):
        continue
    elif not re.search("[0-9]",p):
        continue
    elif not re.search("[A-Z]",p):
        continue
    elif not re.search("[$#@]",p):
        continue
    elif re.search("\s",p):
        continue
    else:
        pass
    value.append(p)
print ",".join(value)
```

Comment: Why would it be recursive? And what's your actual question? You seem to understand the difference between the 2 statements already.

Comment: It's not going through the entire loop multiple times. It just goes through it once whilst skipping some cases.

Comment: @Carcigenicate Since It goes back to the top of the loop, is it not repetitive? cause it would just keep going back up everytime it comes across continue?

Comment: @e_mam106 Except in your example above, `p` changes every iteration of the loop. The loop still advances as normal, `continue` just causes the rest of the loop body to be skipped for that single iteration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`continue` just means "don't execute any of the rest of the loop body this time around".

The next iteration will be exactly the same as if you hadn't `continue`d – that is, your loop variable `p` will be bound to the next element of `items` as usual.

I think that by "recursive" you mean "won't terminate", as in, you suspect that `p` will be bound to the *same* element of `items` as it was last time. This is not what is generally meant be "recursive" – a recursive function is usually understood to be one that explicitly invokes itself, usually with a base case to prevent infinite recursion.

Comment: Thanks it confused me when I read the definition that it goes back to the top of the loop, so i thought behind the scenes it would just run in repetition